# How to do-catch error in init(from decoder:Decoder) from a Codable struct?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, option-type, codable

```
let jsonString = """
                    {
                        "name":1,
                        "gender":"male",
                    }
                    """

struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var gender: String

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        do {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
            gender = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .gender)
        } catch {
            print("XXXXXX \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

From the code above, it won't compile because it complains,

> Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties.

I want to throw some errors but how do I do that without,

1. making default value for every properties.
2. making them all optional.

Comment: Be aware that for this data structure the custom initializer is redundant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need a `do-catch` in `init(from decoder: Decoder)` because it is already marked as `throws`. So just do:

```swift
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    gender = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .gender)
}
```

Whatever does the decoding can use a `do-catch` to see any exception thrown inside the above `init(from:)` method, like in the following example:

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var gender: String

    // Note: This is not a very good example because this init method
    // is not even necessary in this case, since the automatically-
    // synthesized `init(from:)` method does exactly the same thing. I've
    // left it here to illustrate that you don't need to have a `do-catch`
    // in this method and can instead just use `try`, since the method
    // is marked as `throws`.
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        gender = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .gender)
    }
}

class PersonDecoder {
    func person(decodedFrom data: Data) -> Person? {
        do {
            // The `JSONDecoder.decode(_:from:)` method calls
            // `Person.init(from:)`, which can throw, which is why
            // `JSONDecoder.decode(_:from:)` also throws.
            let person = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
            return person
        } catch {
            // Inspect any thrown errors here.
            print(error)

            return nil
        }
    }
}

let personData = Data("""
{
    "name": 1,
    "gender": "male"
}
""".utf8)

let personDecoder = PersonDecoder()

// Prints: "The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."
// and `person` is nil.
let person = personDecoder.person(decodedFrom: personData)
```

Comment: then how to know about the exception?

Comment: @Nuibb Whatever does the decoding can be informed about the exception if you use a `do-catch` around the call to decode the data. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler It doesn't go to catch scope.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler Ok, It does go. but the Swift Error break point need to be edited to continue and not stuck there.

Comment: @hasan I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: The compiler was stuck on the line because of a swift general break point even if I press continue. maybe cause of multiple format problems or something with the behavior of that break point. removing that break point is not convenient for development. but there is many option u can edit on that swift break point to let it pass that line when you press continue. clear now? :D

Comment: there is general break points that you can add in the break points tab. one of them is the swift error break point and other is an objective-c break point.

Comment: Instead of creating a class and an instance method ??? to decode a struct you could simply add a custom initializer to Person `init(_ data: Data)`

Comment: @LeoDabus It was just an example to show something else decoding a `Person` to catch the error.

Comment: sure but it doesn't make any sense. At least make it static

Comment: You don't need an instance. You don't need `self`

Comment: `extension Person {
    init?(_ data: Data) {
        do {
            self = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}`

Comment: or if you what a method to use as an example  just extend Person `extension Person {
    static func decoded(from data: Data) -> Person? {
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
}` usage `let person = Person.decoded(from: data)`